# Tomcat + GeoNetwork: error 404

Tags: tomcat, geonetwork

I tried to install GeoNetwork on a local Tomcat server. I'm using Tomcat 9.0.14 with GeoNetwork version 3.4.4.
I use Ubuntu version 18.04 and Firefox as a web browser.

Tomcat is up and running.
I installed the GeoNetwork application with a .war file copied in the webapps folder. When I deploy it I don't have any error message.

In the localhost:8080/manager page I can see GeoNetwork installed with the status "running=true".

However,when I try to access it via localhost:8080/geonetwork I receive an error 404.

In the catalina.out log file I don't see any error message.

Any idea of the problem that could cause this? I read about every post I could find but I don't find the answer.

Edit:
One of the problem was missing permission for the folder geonetwork (execute I think). Now I have an empty yellow page instead of error 404 and the geonetwork log speak to me, which can be helpful.

> 2018-12-19 09:11:10,853 FATAL [jeeves.engine] - Raised exception during init
>   2018-12-19 09:11:10,853 FATAL [jeeves.engine] -    Exception : org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: I/O error parsing bean definition source for Root WebApplicationContext; nested exception is java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
>   2018-12-19 09:11:10,853 FATAL [jeeves.engine] -    Message   : I/O error parsing bean definition source for Root WebApplicationContext; nested exception is java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
>   2018-12-19 09:11:10,856 FATAL [jeeves.engine] -    Stack     : org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: I/O error parsing bean definition source for Root WebApplicationContext; nested exception is java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException

These are the first lines. Then it fails at creating the db

> 2018-12-19 09:12:55,904 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table Address (id integer not null, address varchar(255), city varchar(255), country varchar(255), state varchar(255), zip varchar(16), primary key (id))

And finally it repeats that the database is read only. I can't find the file geonetwork.h2.db which should at least exist?!
Should I create it myself first to that geonetwork can write in it?

Edit 2 : Somehow it managed to create the geonetwork.h2.db in the /webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/config-db folder. After giving full permission it finally works.

Comment: What happens when you add a trailing slash to the address (`localhost:8080/geonetwork/`)?

Comment: Same error.....

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the operating system and browser in use.

Comment: The default Java version in 18.04 is OpenJDK 10 (or 11). According to their docs, GeoNetwork needs Java 8 - have you specifically installed this and configured Tomcat to use it?

Comment: In the Manager page I see: JVM version 1.8.0_191-b12.